# Qt Creator puts quotation marks around command name in custom process step

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to add a simple custom process step during build to copy a text file from source dir to build dir. The command is just `copy /y sourceFile destFile`, it can't really get any more simple. I have `copy` in command field, and `/y %{sourceDir}\Config.ini %{buildDir}\Config.ini` in arguments field. Qt Creator shows the command as

`copy /y D:\correctSourcePath\Config.ini D:\correctDestPath\Config.ini`

When executed manually, it does exactly what I want it. But when I build the project, it fails, and show the command that is failing as

`"copy" /y D:\correctSourcePath\Config.ini D:\correctDestPath\Config.ini`

For some reason, Qt Creator inserts a pair of quotation marks around the command, which,. of course, completely messes up everything. What's up with this, and how do I get it to stop inserting quotes?

Comment: Please add copy-paste from compile output, to show what is happening, exactly. Problem may be something else than what you think. Also Qt Creator version would be good.

Comment: @hyde, I don't see what's wrong with the `qt` tag. Some users only search for `qt`  tag and they will miss this question.

Comment: @fxam Valid point, it's not entirely inappropriate. I put it back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like Qt Creator is trying to run `copy.exe`, but `copy` is really just an internal command of `cmd.exe`. Try putting your Custom Process Step like this instead:

```
Command: cmd.exe
Arguments: /c copy /y %{sourceDir}\Config.ini %{buildDir}\Config.ini
```

This way, Qt Creator will run `cmd.exe`, which will run its internal `copy` command. **/c** means *carries out the command specified by string and then terminates*. You can run `cmd/?` in Command Prompt for other switches.

Comment: If this is the reason, then using `xcopy` might be another solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` variable in your .pro file. Just add a line like :

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(copy /y D:\correctSourcePath\Config.ini D:\correctDestPath\Config.ini)
```

or

```
SOURCE_DIRECTORY = $$PWD/Config.ini
DESTINATION_DIRECTORY = $$PWD/Config.ini
SOURCE_DIRECTORY ~= s,/,\\,g
DESTINATION_DIRECTORY ~= s,/,\\,g
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(copy /y $${SOURCE_DIRECTORY} $${DESTINATION_DIRECTORY})
```

Comment: Hard-coding absolute paths to .pro files is generally not a good idea (except for throw-away projects which will not be moved or given to other developers).

Comment: @hyde Ofcourse. You can see that there is two possible choices in the answer.

Comment: I ended up using your second variation, but i had to reverse the slashes with "SRC ~= s,/,\\,g" and the like because Windows requires backslashes in it's commands. You might want to edit that into your answer? I accepted @fxams answer as correct because it directly answers the question that was asked, even though I ended up using your solution :(